# Playing video from USB freezes entire system after hours

Tags: freeze, vlc-media-player, usb-storage, video-streaming, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to have an Intel Compute Stick play a playlist of videos non-stop from a USB stick.

Tested with Windows 8 and PowerDVD - runs fine for a week in a row, no problem at all.

Exact same hardware, but with Ubuntu 18.04 and VLC - the whole thing freezes after 12-24 hours. I can't access it in any way once it's frozen, neither via keyboard or remote SSH.

Can't find anything in /var/log/kern.log or syslog. Nothing in /var/crash either.

During the past week I have tried:

- Formatting the USB as ext4 instead of FAT.
- Prevented USB autosuspend in both grub and with a rules.d (really hoped that was it, but no)
- Tried adding settings in /etc/sysctl.conf to make it reboot on kernel panic - didn't work

Copying the videofiles from the USB stick to internal storage, and playing there works! Then it played fine for a week. So it seems to be an issue with the USB stick - not with the graphics driver.

Any ideas on what could be causing this crash when playing from USB on Ubuntu with VLC? Any ideas on something I can try?

Comment: Have you tried using a powered USB hub?  Yes, I realize the implications of my suggestion, I have a specific reason for thinking a externally powered Hub might help.

Comment: No I haven't considered that, because there's no hub connected. I'm only using the single USB port the Compute Stick has for the USB stick. No other devices connected. Also, if it was a power issue, wouldn't it have frozen with Windows 8 too? But I can try it out, no problem.

Comment: Well it didn't like that one bit. Videoplayback is shoppy and slow with an external self-powered USB hub. Sometimes the Compute Stick wouldn't even boot.

Comment: Try another player to rule out a problem with VLC.

Comment: @mr_lou - You might want to read if this particular stick has some known issue surrounding it's USB hub.  Windows and Linux don't deal with USB devices the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after running without problems since posting, everything seems to indicate that the fix was this:

Add "intel_idle.max_cstate=1" to grub.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

After doing this, it's been running fine since.